# Why images dont appear on my website

Tags: php, mysql, imdb

i some images link from imdb(using api 3rd party) and i load it to my sql db and then php app..
but when i click to show all covers they doesent appear :/ why?
i use http://www.omdbapi.com/ api

this is my website, to run click on "Ver Lista de Filmes Capas"
http://web.ist.utl.pt/ist170438/aux/mymdb.php

```
<?php
                try
                {
                $host = "xxxx";
                $user ="xxxx8";
                $password = "xxx";
                $dbname = $user;
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Filme;";
                $result = $db->query($sql);
                $i = 0;
                $per_row = 3;
                echo '<table><tr>';

                foreach ($result as $row)
                {

                echo '<td><img src="'.$row['imageLink'].'" width="200" height="200" /></td>';
                if(++$i % $per_row == 0 && $i > 0 && $i < $count) {
                    # Close the row
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                    }
            }

                for($x = 0; $x < $per_row - $i % $per_row; $x++) {
                 echo '<td></td>';
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';

                /*
                echo("<table border=\"5\" cellspacing=\"5\">\n");
                $per_row = 6;
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                echo '<td><img src="'.$row['imageLink'].'" width="100" height="100" /></td>';
                # If three cells have been printed, and we're not at the last image
                if(++$i % $per_row == 0 && $i > 0 && $i < $count) {
                    # Close the row
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
                # If the last row isn't 'full', fill it with empty cells
                for($x = 0; $x < $per_row - $i % $per_row; $x++) {
                    echo '<td></td>';
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';*/
                $db = null;
                }
                catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                echo("<p>ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}</p>");
                }
        ?>



public void descobreInfoFilme(String nomeFilme, String nomePasta){
        try{
            String urls = KEY_BDAUX + nomeFilme;
            double classificacao = 0;
            String sinopse = null;
            String urlImagem = null;
            String imdbl = "http://www.imdb.com/title/";
            String id= null;
            int ano = 0;
            LinkedList<String> listaGeneros = new LinkedList<String>();     
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is);
            JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
            Filme f = getFilme(nomePasta);
            urlImagem = obj.getString("Poster");
            id = obj.getString("imdbID");
            sinopse = obj.getString("Plot");
            ano = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("Year"));
            listaGeneros.add(obj.getString("Genre"));
            f.setLinkImdb(imdbl + id);
            f.setLinkImagem(urlImagem);
            f.setGenero(listaGeneros);
            f.setSinopse(sinopse);
            f.setAno(ano);
            f.setClassificacao(classificacao);
            listaGeneros = null;

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERRO AO DESCOBRIR informacoes DO IMDB DO FILME " + nomePasta);
            System.out.println("ERRO AO DESCOBRIR informacoes DO IMDB DO FILME " + nomeFilme);
            _listaFilmesErrados.add(nomePasta);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you got any code examples on what you have done so far?

Comment: We need a big warning when you post a question:insert some code!

Comment: Install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), it will show you INSTANTLY that all your image requests come back with resultcode 403, forbidden.  Learning how to use Firebug is a great investment if you're serious about web development

Comment: i didnt put code, cause i dont know what sould i post.. but thanks for downvode

Comment: What is the `public void descobreInfoFilme` in your question - is that Java? I am not sure how it relates to the PHP issue?

Comment: i really dont know why people downvote me so hard.. u just ask if there is a way to get imdb image.. if that is forbidden the just tell me that or do what steebchen have done, tell me a way to fix.. download image(legal) and store in my website.. no really need to hold as off-topic or downvote me 4 times....

Comment: @user3046650: I didn't downvote, but I can speculate as to why four people did so. If you initially posted without code, then it would have been impossible to answer, and helpers here sometimes get frustrated with that sort of question (too broad, not enough detail). Secondly (since your English is fine) please try to post in sentence case (i.e. with an initial cap) and avoid "txt" contractions (especially "u" instead of "you"). Best of luck for your future questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly linking to IMDB images. There is most likely a hotlink protection that prevents you from doing it.

You should host the images yourself and not use bandwidth from other sites.

Comment: i need to download that? really?

Comment: @user3046650 the good people @ IMDB also have hosting costs, and it's their damn good right to invest these costs in effective visitors, by keeping content leechers out.

Comment: you should host them self, **after** getting **permission** from the copyright holders to do so

Answer (score 0):

There is a protection, just download the pictures, and put it in your website's directory. This will also prevent that the files will never get offline, so less work for you.